# Distance 0 value in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

To visualise my sampling data i have to make histograms to see if the frequency of observations decreases when the distance becomes larger.

During the sampling period i visualised by data in my excel sheets utilising the histogram function and this resulted in this:

[image: Excel histogram distances].

Now i have to recreate these histograms in Rstudio to be able to work with the data and later plot model-functions using Distance Software.

But i seem to be running into some problems regarding making histograms.

Utilising the hist() function i was able to recreate the excel histogram utilising the code below.

```r
hist(WPTD2$Distance, xlab = 'Distance', ylab = 'Number of Observations', main = 'Distances of individual woodpigeons during sampling 1-4', col = 'skyblue', breaks = seq(from=0,to=100,by=5))
```

[image: Histogram in Rstudio - Hist() function]

However, i tried the same process but utilising ggplot because this was recommended but i can't seem to get the same results. Even though the bins are the same with n=5 the frequency/observations don't match with the excel or hist() function plotted histograms.

The code is used was:

```r
ggplot(WPTD2, aes(x=Distance)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
```

[image: Histogram in Rstudio- ggplot() function]

Comment: In the `hist` function, you set the bins manually by the `breaks = seq(from = 0,to = 100,by = 5)` command. In the `geom_histogram` you only set the width of the bins, but not specifically the start and end points. These are caluclated automatically by the `geom_histogram` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009038/why-does-geom-histogram-start-at-negative-bin-lower-limit-even-though-all-values for how you can manually set them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the breaks to most closely match the `hist` output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = sample(x = 1:100, 200, replace = TRUE, prob = 1/1:100)) 


df |>
  mutate(bin = cut(a, breaks = seq(from=0,to=100,by=5),
                   include.lowest = TRUE)) |> 
  count(bin)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 2
#>    bin          n
#>    <fct>    <int>
#>  1 [0,5]       80
#>  2 (5,10]      36
#>  3 (10,15]     13
#>  4 (15,20]     10
#>  5 (20,25]     14
#>  6 (25,30]      7
#>  7 (30,35]      8
#>  8 (35,40]      2
#>  9 (40,45]      2
#> 10 (45,50]      1
#> 11 (50,55]      5
#> 12 (55,60]      4
#> 13 (60,65]      1
#> 14 (65,70]      2
#> 15 (70,75]      1
#> 16 (75,80]      4
#> 17 (80,85]      1
#> 18 (85,90]      4
#> 19 (90,95]      2
#> 20 (95,100]     3

hist(df$a, breaks = seq(from=0, to=100,by=5))
```

[image]

```r
df |> 
  ggplot(aes(a)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 90, 10)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(from=0, to=100,by=5),
                 closed = "right")
```

[image]